# Web UI framework for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Is there a "BlackBerry UI" CSS/JS framework available for Blackberry - Similar to IUI for the iPhone?

Hosted over on Google Code http://code.google.com/p/iui/ there is a great open source library for providing a "standard" iPhone UI for web applications.

i.e. a JavaScript and CSS library to provide:

- BlackBerry look and feel
- Data Binding
- Curved corners etc.
- DOM utilities
- Handle idiosyncrasies between browser versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact UI changes across blackberry hardware, I guess it's difficult to create the equivalent of what is found on iOS.

I'm referring you to this forum thread you already saw for sure: [Is there a "BlackBerry UI" CSS/JS framework for BB's - Similar to IUI for the iPhone](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Is-there-a-quot-BlackBerry-UI-quot-CSS-JS-framework-for-BB-s/td-p/228082)

In term of compatibility and usability, I guess slightly altering a [jQuery Mobile's](http://www.jquerymobile.com) theme would be your best option if you want to find one that is open source (unlike [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) for example).

Answer (score 1):

BB OS 6 contains a modern Webkit browser so it's easier to use standard toolkits such as Sencha.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using Jquery Mobile or Sencha, you could give a try to this (official it seems) library https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using jQuery Mobile on a BlackBerry app.

It's slow (especially on older/less powerful devices), bloated (lots of stuff you probably won't ever need), the UI doesn't align with BlackBerry guidelines whatsoever and it doesn't play well with focus-based navigation (which is important as some current devices still don't have a touch screen and some users prefer to navigate with the trackpad).

bbUI.js (https://github.com/tneil/bbUI.js) as mentioned by [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189687/max) is an official library originally developed by someone at RIM and, while it's not without its flaws and limitations, after months of working on a large WebWorks project it is still the best choice I've found to get up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, the OS 6 browser crashes at the mere hint of javascript load (most usually the case), slightly less from having too many tabs open (by "too many", the amouny ranges between two on the lower spec models like 9300 to 4 or 5 on the 9780). This is from my experiences. Perhaps my settings are wrong - I tend to like smaller text, Arial and set the encoding to UTF-8. 
However, I have never had Opera crash on the same phones - despite having at least 5 to 10 tabs open and in the background.